# by using kivymd md datatable how to make checkbox checked when I press the row

Tags: python, datatable, kivymd

I am trying to make app that have md datatable

```
def on_row_pressed(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        instance_row.check = True
```

that my code for on_row_press method but it did not work

I need to make the checkbox checked when I click the row
can any one help?

def on_row_pressed(self, instance_table, instance_row):
instance_row.check = True

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but I hope it will help.

For this solution you have to click on the column 1 to check the checkbox.
If you want to check the checkbox when you click the column 2 make sure to know in which instance of row you are and it has a visible checkbox or not.

```
class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"

        layout = AnchorLayout()
        data_tables = MDDataTable(
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            check=True,
            use_pagination=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(100)),
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                (f"{i + 1}", "1") for i in range(10)
            ],
        )
        def on_row_press(self, instance_row):
            '''Called when a table row is clicked.'''
            if instance_row.ids.check.state == "normal":
                instance_row.change_check_state_no_notify("down")
            elif  instance_row.ids.check.state == "down":
                instance_row.change_check_state_no_notify("normal")
            else:
                print("nothing")
        data_tables.bind(on_row_press=on_row_press)
        layout.add_widget(data_tables)
        return layout
Example().run()
```